# Solr query with "AND"ing based on differing values in a doc field

Tags: solr

I've worked with solr some in the past, but mostly the searching has been straight forward.  We've now got a situation where we'd like to have searches that can restrict results on an "AND" ... using the example as follows:

Doc 1 --> StudentID:123 ClassID: 001

Doc 2 --> StudentID:123 ClassID:002

Doc 3 --> StudentID:987 ClassID:001

The "English" version of the desired query would be "Give me all students in classes with classID:001 and ClassID:002.  This would only return StudentID:123 and leave out Student:987.

Granted, our actually query is much more complex than this b/c the class could also have other properties like time, day, etc.  But I wanted to see if I could get some help in accomplishing the basic "AND" filtering first.

This is how we are currently implementing it and it "seems" to work, but since the number of classes can be dynamic, it means we'll need to dynamically update the mincount.  Just curious if there's a "better" way of doing it.

```
q=*:*&fq=(ClassID:001)OR(ClassID:002)&rows=0&group=true&group.field=ClassID&group.facet=true&group.ngroups=true&facet=true&facet.field=ClassID&facet.mincount=2&facet.field=StudentID
```

I'm sure there's a straight forward way that I haven't found yet, so I'm handing the question off to the experts.  Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could set your `default operator` in your `schema.xml` to be `OR`. This assumes that all (or most) of the cases would want to do an OR querying.

Then you could change your query to be something like this:

```
classId:('001' '002')
```

Since your class Ids are dynamic, you could inject this value by joining a list of `classid`s from your client .